# ASP.NET Web API - cloned objects when POST executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp.net-web-api

currently I'm learning how to develop ASP.NET Web API used applications. I created simple Web API using these objects and Visual Studio generated Controllers (using Entity Framework).

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Names { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class CustomTask
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    [Required]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Technology { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long EstimatedTime { get; set; }
    public long RealTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Required]
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Required]
    public bool Lessons { get; set; }
    public string ArchiveID { get; set; }
}
```

At client side (written in WinForms) I am trying to add `CustomTask` to existing `Client` that way:

```
public static async Task PostObjectToAPI(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        string typeName = obj.GetType().Name;
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/" + typeName + "s/", obj);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            throw new APIexception(content);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private async void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomTask obj = new CustomTask();
    obj.Client = clientSelected;
    obj.ClientID = clientSelected.ID;
    // getting rest of properties, I checked and it works good
    await Connection.PostObjectToAPI(obj);
}
```

Problem is weird for me:

I add for example new CustomTask with ClientID = 2
New CustomTask is created, but additionally new Client is created, whose all properties are the same except ID. For example this cloned Client has ID = 5
Recently created CustomTask's ClientID is 5 instead of 2.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help

**EDIT:**

Deleting `obj.Client = clientSelected;` line solved the problem.

Comment: The description of the problem is unclear. Please try to rephrase and state clearly where something goes wrong (which line of the code for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you create Client object which EF is not tracking, that's why when you do `SaveChanges()` it creates a new one. So, you have two options:

- delete the line `obj.Client = clientSelected;` - this is navigational property and is populated for you once you save changes
- attach the object to context to track and mark it as 'unchanged': `context.Attach(clientSelected)`

Comment: Really BIG thanks, I have deleted `obj.Client = clientSelected;` and everything works fine now.